# Date Query in JPA

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0

How To write Query in JPA base on month selection.

E.g.

There is column effective_date in the table which contains dates values shown below records

```
1 May 
1 Jun
2 July 
1 Aug
```

and if current_date is 8 July then it show return 2 July Record

How write such query to retrieve record base on Effective date using JPA

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you be storing the actual date rather than the month string, this approach seems limited to 1 years worth of data, unless it doesn't matter which year?

Also its very difficult to suggest a code solution without knowing what your entity or entity property (effective_date) is called.

something like

```
EntityManager em = //a reference to your entityManager
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT effectiveDate FROM UnknownEntityName");
List<UnknownEntityName> results = (List<UnknownEntityName>) q.getResultList();
```

try looking here for some more useful pointers

[JPA Tutorial](http://footyntech.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/java-persistence-api-a-quick-intro/)

Comment: effective_date column contains date value not 1 May string value. I just gave example to understand the question

Comment: In that case the above code should work. You can change the query to select the entity (still unsure of the name) where the date matches a date, or is between a date range.